# I can not handle these classes c# uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

until now I only have small applications, but now I can not handle these classes c# uwp

I want to break the code into several classes, each class will deal with a few parameters. classes will send parameter values to the main page. but when I try to display those parameters, they are always zero, even though the text file appears modified.

i have main page

```
namespace airflow
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

    }

    public MainPage()
    {

    }

    private async void main_page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            param_perimetrala read = new param_perimetrala();
            ora_start_perimetrala = read.start_perimetrala;
            var mesaj = new MessageDialog(ora_start_perimetrala.ToString());
            var res = await mesaj.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

and a class

```
namespace airflow
{
    public class param_perimetrala
    {
        public static int ora_start_perimetrala;
        public int minut_start_perimetrala;
        public int ora_stop_perimetrala;
        public int minut_stop_perimetrala;
        public int ore_ciclu_perimetrala;
        public int minut_ciclu_perimetrala;
        public int contor_ore_perimetrala = 0;
        public int contor_minute_perimetrala = 0;
        public int contor_sec_perimetrala = 0;

        public async void readfile_perimetrala()
        {
            StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile perimetrala_file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("parametrii_perimetrala.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            var readFile_perimetrala = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(perimetrala_file);
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var line in readFile_perimetrala)
            {
                string[] split_perimetrala = line.Split(new string[] { "=" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var temp = split_perimetrala[1];
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    ora_start_perimetrala = Int32.Parse(temp);
                }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    minut_start_perimetrala = Int32.Parse(temp);
                }
                if (count == 2)
                {
                    ora_stop_perimetrala = Int32.Parse(temp);
                }

                count = count + 1;
            }
        }

        public int start_perimetrala
        {
            get { return ora_start_perimetrala; }
            set { ora_start_perimetrala = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

how to send ora_start_perimetrala value in mainpage?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6mFe.png)

Comment: You never give it a value and the default for `int` is zero. What are you expecting?

Comment: if (count == 0)
                        {
                                ora_start_perimetrala = Int32.Parse(temp);
                        }

Comment: I don't see you displaying that value after setting it. Is there more code?

Comment: And we don't see a call to `readfile_perimetrala`. Please provide a verifiable example. As it is, we don't know what is going on or even what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want to display it in main page

Comment: private async void main_page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            param_perimetrala read = new param_perimetrala();
            ora_start_perimetrala = read.start_perimetrala;
            var mesaj = new MessageDialog(ora_start_perimetrala.ToString());
            var res = await mesaj.ShowAsync();
    }

Comment: @UngureanuVictor: **Edit the question**, don't just put an addition in comment on your own question. Look at your comment. Do you find that in any way readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main_page_Loaded` event handler method you are calling `read_file_perimetrala` but `read_file_perimetrala` is `async void`. This means as soon as you get to an `await` statement, and the await is actually awaitable (not returned immediately) then the method will put the rest of the work aside until the awaited portion is complete.  Then it picks back up and runs the rest.  During that time of placing it aside the calling thread then continues to run wherever it's needed.

You need to make this a Task and await the call to is also so that you can insure the parameters are filled before continuing work.

Change your `readFile_perimetrala` to be like so:

```
public async Task readfile_perimetralaAsync()
```

Change the entire `main_page_Loaded` event handler to read like so...

```
private async void main_page_Loaded(object sender)
{
    param_perimetrala read = new param_perimetrala();
    await read.readfile_perimetralaAsync();
    var mesaj = new MessageDialog(read.start_perimetrala.ToString());
    var res = await mesaj.ShowAsync();
}
```

In your code you're assigning the value to a method but I can tell that you want the int value.

Just some light weight examples to help get started understanding Task and async await.  Don't use this as a resource but just enough to get you curious to dig deeper because it's a simple but rather deep subject.

```
public class TaskExamples
{       
    public async void DoAsyncVoid()
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
    }
    public async Task DoAsyncTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
    }

    public async Task<int> DoReturnValueTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
        return 50;
    }

    public async void CallingTasks()
    {
        DoAsyncVoid(); //This can't use await because it is 'void' so the next line is ran as soon as this command reaches the first 'true awaitable' await.
        await DoAsyncTask(); //This runs before DoAsyncVoid is complete.
        var value = await DoReturnValueTask(); //This waits until 'DoAsyncTask' is complete because it is a Task and awaited.
        await new MessageDialog(value.ToString()).ShowAsync(); //This waits until 'DoReturnValueTask' is complete and value will be 50 in this case.

        //All code here waits until the Dialog is closed because it is also awaited.
    }
}
```

Comment: Error CS4001 Cannot await 'method group'

Comment: @UngureanuVictor  Ok, I'm updating my answer.  That was the first issue I saw but there's more to the situation.

Comment: Am I blind? I don't see any calls to read_file_perimetrala in OPs code.

Comment: @UngureanuVictor No problem.. I'm updating the answer with some task examples just to get you started.  There's a lot more to tasks so don't take this as a tutorial but more of getting your feet wet and working in the right direction.

Comment: @Crowcoder Its' the first method (only method) in his ```param_perimetrala``` class.  It's just a little harder to see write away because his C# code isn't written in standard and the formatting of the question isn't good.